# Select from two tables Where not exists

Tags: php, sql, database

I have two tables:

**table 1**

```
id       int(11)
name     varchar(255)
email    varchar(255)
```

**table 2**

```
id       int(11)
name     varchar(255)
email    varchar(255)
```

Both have a few thousand entries in. The problem is they need to be identical and table 2 has some missing.

**How can I check what emails in table1 are not in table 2 and then output them to the page?**

I have tried:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email
                             FROM table2 b
                             WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                             SELECT *
                             FROM table1 a
                             WHERE a.email = b.email)");
```

but When I var_dump $result it returns Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're backwards. The query you have will give you the records in `table2` that are not in `table1`.

You want:

```
SELECT email
FROM table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2 b
    WHERE b.email = a.email
)
```

i.e. "select emails from table1 where there isn't one in table2"

Comment: Still var_dump is Null

Comment: `$result` shouldn't be `NULL`, and this sounds like a different problem... Are you sure you've set up the connection right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT email FROM Table1 a WHERE email not in(select email from table2 WHERE not email is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to avoid nested selects if possible:

```
SELECT a.email
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.email = b.email
WHERE b.email IS NULL
```

That should find any email addresses that exist in table1 but *not* table2.

If you then need to dump that output to screen, instead of `var_dump`ing the result (as the result will be a `mysqli_result` object) you could:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT a.email FROM table1 AS a LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON a.email = b.email WHERE b.email IS NULL");

if($result) {
  var_dump($result->fetch_all());
}
else {
  echo $con->error();
}
```